# Erasing elements from a vector satisfying a vector of condition

Tags: loops, vector, physics

```
for (int i=0;i<matSize;i++) 
{

    if(condition[i]==1)
    {
    displacement.erase (displacement.begin()+i);
    }

 }
```

What is wrong with this loop? I'm trying to remove elements from the displacement vector that meet the condition. I could not get erase to work in loop. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: What language is this? What are the variables involved declared as? What is the result (expected/actual)? Read the stackoverflow manual http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'll go out on a limb and suppose that this is C++, and you're using std::vector.

Suppose there are 5 elements in the vector. After you erase one, how many are left? Which one will you check next, and how high will you count?

To be more explicit, suppose it's

```
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]
```

and you want to erase the 10 and the 20. So when `i` is 1, you test the 10 and erase it; now the vector is

```
[0, 20, 30, 40]
```

You then increment `i` to 2, and check 30, *having missed 20 entirely*. And you'll be in bigger trouble when you iterate past the end (i.e when `i` is 4).

The solution is simple, and you could have discovered all of this by trying your code on a small, simple vector and seeing which elements you were testing and erasing.